# Why does an order still come through on Magento if the customer uses an invalid debit/credit card?

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, ce-1.9.0.1, sales

When a customer uses an invalid debit/credit card on a Magento checkout, is there a reason as to why the order still comes through to the orders section?

The order says it is pending payment even though no credit/debit card information has come through.